# Does SystemVerilog support conditional compilation based on the tool analysing the file?

Tags: system-verilog

Does SystemVerilog contain a feature whereby it is able to detect what program is compiling the code (for synthesis or simulation) and then include or exclude sections of file for processing?

This feature could be used to declare "simulation only" code blocks and also write portable code whereby a design block instantiates different IP depending on wheather it is being compiled by Quartus, Libero or some other FPGA compiler.

Comment: This feature has been introduced into VHDL 2019 as "Conditional analysis tool directives"

Comment: Usual way would just be `generate` depending on a parameter passed to the compiler, or an `ifdef`.

Comment: In VHDL a limited form has always been available as some variation of `-- pragma translate off` (and on) if you merely need to distinguish between synthesis (obeys the pragma) and simulation (does not). I'd expect something similar in Verilog surely? Extending to different synth tools ... no. But you can pass a different value to a generic from different synthesis scripts, and "if ... generate" or use configurations.

Comment: VHDL has generate and pragma, but it is not enough to create truly portable code. If we have a VHDL block that contains IP from two different VHDL vendors and want to be able to compile it across both vendors, it is impossible since each vendor does not identity the IP component of the other vendor. It does not matter if I use generate or pragma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called the conditional compile construct `` `ifdef `` or `` `ifndef ``. For examples

```
module foo(...);

`ifdef SYNTHESIS
  // code to be synthesised
`else
  // code not to be synthesized
`endif

endmodule
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58996919/how-to-determine-that-synthesis-is-done-in-quartus

Comment: yes but this is not sufficient, can systemverilog find out which tool is compiling or simulating the code i.e the tool name and version number?

Comment: The link I provided in my answer shows quartus providing the tool name for synthesis. But you would have to know the tool name in advance. Your command line scripts could easily provide generic tool name and version definitions.